# Scaling probabilities based on various conditions

Tags: probability, optimization

Suppose initially that we are given a random set of three probabilities $p_1$, $p_2,$ and $p_3$ (e.g. $p_1 = 0.3$, $p_2 = 0.5$, and $p_3 = 0.2$). I want to increase $p_1$ (and thus decrease $p_2$) or increase $p_2$ (and thus decrease $p_1$) keeping $p_3$ fixed based on various rules. What would be a good way of doing this?

In the above example, consider two cases:

**Case 1**: Increase $p_1$, decrease $p_2$, and keep $p_3$ fixed. Then we would want to find $a \in [0,1]$ and $b \in [1, \infty)$ such that $ap_1 +bp_2+p_3 = 1$.

**Case 2**: Decrease $p_1$, increase $p_2$, and keep $p_3$ fixed. Then we would want to find $a \in  [1, \infty)$ and $b \in [0,1]$ such that $ap_1 +bp_2+p_3 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a fixed $p_3$.

You know that $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$.

With these two constraints, the new value of $p_1$ must lie between $0$ and $1-p_3$.

Let $\Delta p_1$ be the change in $p_1$. That is, $p_{1_{new}}=p_{1_{old}}+\Delta p_1$

You can choose your value of $\Delta p_1$ as long as $-p_1\le \Delta p_1\le 1-p_3-p_1$

The change to $p_2$ follows automatically: $p_{2_{new}}=p_{2_{old}}-\Delta p_1$